# Unable to execute a shell script in android shell

Tags: android, linux, bash, shell

I am trying tun a shell script from android shell.
Please see the output below.

```
root@user:/data # ./run_script.sh
/system/bin/sh: ./run_script.sh: No such file or directory

root@user:/data # ls -l run_script.sh
-rwxrwxrwx root     root         5861 2016-11-14 07:31 run_script.sh
```

Why is it saying "No such file or directory" The error is strange as the file is actually present.

I tried copying the same shell script to /system partition as well. The result is same. I verified from mount command that both the partitions are not mounted with `noexec` flag.

I am able to get it working with `sh run_script` but I want to get it working by executing directly.

Comment: does a file have required permissions? (execute)

Comment: Yes 777 are the permissions. In the code snippet i showed the permissions

Comment: oh, right, sorry, I've missed it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Usually this happens when a shebang is not correct. Check if you have a "#!..." at the start of the script and remove it or correct it

Comment: I have #!/bin/sh I tried changing it to #!/bin/bash.. Both ways the result is same

Comment: you have to remove it or put: "#!/system/bin/sh" (no quotes)

Comment: Thank you so much. It worked.. I have one more query.. My script is a big one. In the middle of execution I see an error as follows "./run_script: //: can't execute: Is a directory" error. Any Idea why do we see this

Comment: Looks line it's trying to execute a directory, you might want to run it as **"sh -x run_script.sh"** : "-x xtrace        Write each command to standard error (preceded by a ‘+ ’) before it is executed.  Useful for debugging.his will print out in "debug" mode" and see exactly what's going on.

Comment: Thanks A lot rift85. You have saved me a lot time.

Comment: Hi, I have sed inside my shell script, I get the following error "sed: No such file or directory" I see that sed is present in the system. Why do I see this error? Any idea?

Comment: Try to write the whole path to sed inside of the script. Find out where sed is: `> which sed
/bin/sed` and replace the sed command inside of the scrip with the full path , ex "/bin/sed 's/ex/ex/g'"

Comment: Actually it seems an issue with sed toybox on marshmallow. I cherry-picked the patch in here and it looks fine now. Thank you again. You have been very helpful.. http://lists.landley.net/pipermail/toybox-landley.net/2015-September/004415.html

Comment: Hi, I posted a new question on shell scripts - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40622680/in-linux-shell-scripts-what-does-x-131-mean Please comment you answer there if possible.

Answer (score 0):

file format reason
maybe you create file in windows,then push it to phone.
cat command ,can not see it.
use vi,we can see

## !/bin/sh^M

ps^M